# How use php from another docker container

Tags: php, docker, supervisord

in my app i have separated docker containers for nginx, mysql, php and supervisor. But now i require set in supervisor a program which run php script. It`s possible call php from another container?

EDIT

Example:

When i run supervisor program `test`, then i see error: `INFO spawnerr: can't find command 'php'`. I know that php is not in the container `supervisor`, but how i call from container `php`? And i require same php as for application.

./app/test.php

```
<?php
echo "hello world";
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"

services:
  nginx:
    build: ./docker/nginx
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
    links:
      - php
      - mysql
  php:
    build: ./docker/php
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 9001:9001
  mysql:
    build: ./docker/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  supervisor:
    build: ./docker/supervisor
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
```

supervisor.conf

```
[program:test]
command = php /var/www/html/test.php
process_name = %(process_num)02d
numprocs = 1
autostart = false
autorestart = true
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Maybe you can add an example of how the containers currently run and connect to each other and where you are trying to add the PHP script?

Comment: Provide more info. How did you separate them? Is it one `docker-compose.yml` or you started multiple containers with separate `docker run` calls?

Answer (score -1):

Please check this repo in [github](https://github.com/J-Ibarra/dockerangularlaravelmongo)

I used angular, laravel and mongo
with 3 containers, for mongo, php-fpm and nginx to make proxi to api and angular.

Angular dose not use nodejs container because I build angular `ng build` and this out the build in the folder angular-dist.

The folder angular-src its the source code of angular

into folder laravel run the command `composer install`, if you use **Linux** use `sudo chmod 777 -R laravel`

you can see this

[image]

and the route http://localhost:8000/api/

[image]

and the route http://localhost:8000/api/v1.0

[image]